# Getting undefined from akshat.age object, instead i should be getting a numeric value

Tags: javascript

```
const akshat = {
    firstName:'Akshat',
    lastName:'Saxena',
    birthYear:1994,
    job:'programmer',
    friends:['Paras','Rachit','Pushpendra'],
    hasDriverLicense: true,

    calcAge:function(){
        this.age = 2037 - this.birthYear;
    }

};

console.log(akshat.age);
```

Answer (score 1):

`age` is set when `calcAge` is called:

```js
const akshat = { 
  firstName:'Akshat', 
  lastName:'Saxena', 
  birthYear:1994, 
  job:'programmer', 
  friends:['Paras','Rachit','Pushpendra'], 
  hasDriverLicense: true,
  calcAge:function(){
    this.age = 2037 - this.birthYear;
  }
};

akshat.calcAge(); // set age

console.log(akshat.age);
```

Comment: Does that mean age will be set in the object only after we call the method once?

Comment: @AkshatSaxena yes.

Comment: @AkshatSaxena age is set inside the function, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

The object does not have its own age property. The property is set when we run the function `calcAge()`. If you try to access the `age` property without running the function, you will get `undefined` as `age` is not defined. So, you need to first run the `calcAge` method like below -

```js
const akshat = { 
  firstName:'Akshat', 
  lastName:'Saxena', 
  birthYear:1994, 
  job:'programmer', 
  friends:['Paras','Rachit','Pushpendra'], 
  hasDriverLicense: true,
  calcAge:function(){
    this.age = 2037 - this.birthYear;
  }
};

console.log(akshat.age); //undefined

akshat.calcAge(); // set age

console.log(akshat.age); //43
```